# Random banner positioning on website's page. Possible?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Can someone tell me how I can achieve the following?

I want to display a banner on my website's page (of course this is easy). However I want it to appear randomly (a single time) in one of the 4 positions I selected (DIV ID's bannerpos1, bannerpos2, bannerpos3 and bannerpos4).

If the banner shows up in bannerpos2, it shouldn't appear at any other location and vice versa.

And, only if possible, it should display a random banner as well (choice out of 3 banners or so).

So in short; I want a random banner in a random position on my page. Of course the banners and positions are yet to be defined.

Can someone help me, or point me in the right direction?

//update 7th of November

Okay, I have been fooling around with the script as show by Joe, however I am experiencing some problems...

Currently the code looks like this (before body-tage):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
var position = Math.floor((Math.random()*3));
console.log(position)

var $a = $("#advertentieplaats1");
var $b = $("#advertentieplaats2");
var $c = $("#advertentieplaats3");

var $advertentietype1 = $("#advinhoud1");
var $advertentietype2 = $("#advinhoud2");
var $advertentietype3 = $("#advinhoud3");

if (position == 0){
    $a.append($advertentietype1);
}
if (position == 1){
    $b.append($advertentietype2);
}
if (position == 2){
    $c.append($advertentietype3);
}
});
</script>
```

And at the bottom of the page I have the following:

```
<div id="advinhoud1">adsense code 1</div>
<div id="advinhoud2">adsense code 2</div>
<div id="advinhoud3">adsense code 3</div>
```

Or there are some problems with this, or I am doing it wrong somehow...

In Firefox it shows the adsense code on random (defined) locations. It also shows the remaining 2 advertisements at the bottom (which should not be visible or even loaded).

In Internet Explorer it doesn't do anything at all...? All Adsense is shown at the bottom, nothing in random locations...?

Comment: It's not very difficult. Design the three banners. Define CSS classes for the 4 different positions and then, using Math.random(), pick a banner and a position and apply them.

Comment: I always read "it's not difficult" as "I don't think this is difficult so you shouldn't either".

Comment: @Joe It was intended to mean "it ceratinly is possible", seeing as the OP wasn't  sure. But I see what you mean.

Comment: Sorry perhaps I misread your comment. I love SO as a serious resource for serious programmers but I do think newcomers are sometimes treated badly and put off! I know I've been guilty of it in the past, so I try to be careful. Perhaps I'm over-sensitive to it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this. You can make it more dynamic, but here's the idea.

```
var position = Math.floor((Math.random()*3));
var $a = $("#myDiv1"); // Get the three containers as JQuery objects by id.
var $b = $("#myDiv1");
var $c = $("#myDiv1");
var $myAd = $("#myAd"); // Get the content you want to place.
                        // You could include it as a string in your JS 
                        // or as a hidden element.
if (position == 0)
{
    $a.append($myAd);
}

if (position == 1)
{
    $b.append($myAd);
}

if (position == 2)
{
    $c.append($myAd);
}
```

Comment: Thanks Joe for the answer. Hopefully I can make this work. I am pretty new to this and I only know some CSS and HTML. Anyways thank you for your time.

Comment: I made a quick JSFiddle. It looks like the JavaScript random number generator isn't quite up to the job (I think it re-seeds every time you reset?). You should look into random number generation, there's lots of code out there. http://jsfiddle.net/QCVXx/

Comment: Thanks once again Joe! Highly appreciated.

Comment: Hi Joe, I finally understood the code example you gave me and it's working great. Highly appreciated and thanks once again for the help!

Comment: Oh one more thing; which just come to mind. How does this work in real-life with Google's Adsense? I already have 2 advertisements on the page and therefor I have only room for one more. Will the script preload 3 new advetisements? If so, that probably won't work, because I already have 2 on the page. Or did I misunderstood something here? Or, in other words, will it only load the advertisement code which is being selected from the script?

Comment: The way I showed you, which is one way you could do it (there are other ways) you load the ads directly into the HTML but only show one to the user. Be careful with AdSense, they probably have policies that you have to be aware of.